# Jenkins pipeline script: stashing and unstashing between nodes - how is network traffic handled?

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins master/slave setup. I want to transfer files of the order of ~100 MB between two slaves. I use the stash/unstash functionality that comes with jenkins.

```
node ('somenode') {
    stage('Checkout and build') {
        //some Checkout and build
    }
    stage('Stash') {
        stash includes: 'someDirectory/**', name: 'myFirstStash'
    }
}
node ('someOtherNode') {
    stage('Unstash') {
        String archivePath = '/somePath/someFolder'
        dir (archivePath) {
            unstash 'myFirstStash'
        }
    }
}
```

A bit of context:
In this particular example, we have a rather tiny jenkins master with not a lot of memory and computing power and very little hard drive space. 
Connected to it are 70 jenkins slaves that are very powerful. (Infrastructure provided by IT department, I know that the setup is not ideal).

My questions are:

- How much stress does this put on the master?
- How is the network connection handled?
- Is this bad practice?
- I assume the files are stashed on the master in a temporary directory. Is this cleaned up immediately after the pipeline finishes?
- In my current setup, the 'Stash' stage in the example above takes about 2 minutes while the unstash takes more than 20 minutes. Is this general stash/unstash behaviour or is this something internal to the slaves? (more context: Stash takes place on linux, unstash on windows into a network drive)

Thank you for your help.